# Do empirical indices exist to evaluate and contrast Foreign Policy programs of heads of state?

Tags: foreign-policy, indicators

Empirical indices exist to measure [happiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happiness_economics) (and misery), [economic freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_freedom#Indices_of_economic_freedom), [wealth inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_inequality_metrics), and a host of other outcomes of public policy.  Are there any in existence that seek to measure the effectiveness of Foreign Policy?

Such an index would possibly include:

1. The ability to protect national interests
2. The ability to project national power effectively and efficiently
3. The ability to build international coalitions
4. Evaluation of trade policy
5. Evaluation of diplomacy (to persuade, uphold legality of treaties and international positions, etcetera.)
6. Evaluation of foreign aid effectiveness
7. Evaluation of international intelligence to identify emerging threats, etc.

Has anyone come across such a thing, or an attempt at measuring such a thing across countries and administrations/regimes?

Comment: I would guess that various intelligence agencies have ways of measuring these factors, but I doubt that there's an accurate public database or anything like that. If we assume that actors are the ones who best know their own capabilities, it seems that there's an  equilibrium where nobody is interested in making this data publicly available.

Comment: There are a few "Soft Power indices" which are related. The problem is that even the different hard powers (such as military, economic, legal) are hard to compare.